# Plugin is installed and activated, still I can't find it to add as a widget

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm sort of new to the Wordpress scene, so probably I'm making an obvious mistake.

I installed this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/flickr-justified-gallery/

It's installed and activated, however, when I try to add it to my site it's not there as a widget, I can't use it at all.

I've tried other similar plugin, the "photo gallery" plugin, and that one I could find without any issues, not sure why this one I can't.

Anyway, I'm looking for a plugin that behaves similarly to how Flickr shows images.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have a widget: widgets are for sidebars, this is intended for the content of a post/page.

Take a look at the [installation instructions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/flickr-justified-gallery/installation/): you should insert the shortcode `[flickr_photostream]` in your post/page content after having configured the plugin settings.

Comment: I don't completely understand, I want my site to have a button somewhere, even it could be a menu (just like Flickr "explore" menu option) , where after clicked it leads me to this gallery. Is this plugin useful for that purposes or not?.

Comment: this is not _like_ flickr, it is **for** flickr, that is you need to have an account on flickr with your photos (if I understood correctly your issue, if not please help me understand it)

Comment: Oh.. I see, I thought it was just a improved version of a photo gallery... My bad. Do you know of any plugin that can work like that?. (A photo gallery flickr style)

Comment: I installed the FooGallery, and maybe I'm missing something, but I still can't see the gallery as a widget.

Comment: why are you looking for a widget? do you need to load the gallery inside a sidebar? as I said in my answer this galleries are usually loaded into the content of a post/page, and even in this case there should be a shortcode to insert. take a look at the [tutorial](http://docs.fooplugins.com/foogallery/foogallery-101/), maybe it will clarify your doubts